# Compressing slightly bigger file resulted in smaller zipped file?

Tags: compression, zip, 7zip

I first zipped a Visual Studio project folder which turned out to be 14,100 kb.

I then realized that I needed to add something to my program, so I inserted an additional 50 lines and saved the project again. I zipped it again and this time the zipped file was 14,087 kb.

Now I expected an equal or larger zip file, not a smaller one. What exactly happened here and how is this possible to get a smaller zip file from a larger project folder? I also rezipped the same project folder a third time just to make sure and it was 14,087 kb again.

Comment: There's no way to tell without carefully comparing the two zipped files. All we can do is guess.

Comment: Is there any sort of randomness in the process of zipping? It just doesn't make any sense to me how zipping a larger folder results in a smaller zipped file.

Comment: If you just want to know how it could make sense, consider "foofoofoofoo" versus "foofoofoof". The first can compress to "(foo)x4". The second, though shorter and including all of the first one, compresses to "(foo)x3+(f)", which is longer.

Comment: Does kb really mean kilobytes?